# compare string with ng-if angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When i try to compare the string with ng-if from angularjs, i m getting the errors in console.

Below are my data:

value for `{{reports[0]}}` is:

```
{"name":null,"discount":0,"margin":0,"reportType":"REPORT_TOP_SELLERS","revenue":0,"variantKey":null,"rank":1,"productKey":"10692-1_en_US","purchasedUnits":0,"abandonedUnits":0}
```

**value for {{reports[0].reportType}} is:**

```
REPORT_TOP_SELLERS
```

Below are the code which throws the Error:

```
<div ng-if="{{reports[0].reportType}} === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">

Error:
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{reports[0].reportType}} === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'] starting at [{reports[0].reportType}} === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'].
```

Please help.

Comment: brackets binds the model, without brackets it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your response.

Comment: first to answer that too right answer, still accepted copied answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

change html code :

```
<div ng-if="reports[0].reportType == 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

Comment: Can we use pattern inside ng-if? e.g. ng-if="report type has only alphabetical values"
I tried `<div *ngIf="itCovPointInfo['COV_GLOBALS']['rcw'] === '/[a-zA-Z0-9]/'">` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Use without the expression, it should be,

if its **`angular`**

```
<div *ngIf="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

**`angularjs`**

```
<div ng-if="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

Answer (score 3):

do not use brackets just use it direct

```
<div ng-if="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use curly braces

ng-if is already in an angular context so you can just do this

```
<div ng-if="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

double curly braces: `{{ }} ->` are for interpolation

Answer (score 2):

Don't use curly braces,
To only check equality,it should be

```
<div ng-if="reports[0].reportType == 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

To check type and equality,it should be

```
 <div ng-if="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `{{}}`. You don't need interpolation, just access the value directly like:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.reports = [{"name":null,"discount":0,"margin":0,"reportType":"REPORT_TOP_SELLERS","revenue":0,"variantKey":null,"rank":1,"productKey":"10692-1_en_US","purchasedUnits":0,"abandonedUnits":0}];
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-if="reports[0].reportType === 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'">
    Report Type is 'REPORT_TOP_SELLERS'
  </div>
</div>
```